# node.js : fluent-ffmpeg throws error when converting mp4 to mp3

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, mp3, mp4, fluent

I'm trying to convert an mp4 video to mp3 with node's fluent-ffmpeg module. Here is my code:

```
ffmpeg = require 'fluent-ffmpeg'

mp4 = '/Users/jashua/Desktop/video.mp4'
mp3 = '/Users/jashua/Desktop/audio.mp3'

proc = new ffmpeg({source:mp4})
    .toFormat('mp3')
    .setFfMpegPath('/Applications/ffmpeg')
    .saveToFile(mp3, (stdout, stderr)->
            return console.log stderr if err?
            return console.log 'done'
        )
```

On running it, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'saveToFile' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jashua/Desktop/ytdl.coffee:10:12, <js>:18:60)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jashua/Desktop/ytdl.coffee:1:1, <js>:25:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Any ideas?

Solution:

```
proc = new ffmpeg({source:mp4})
    proc.setFfMpegPath('/Applications/ffmpeg')
    proc.saveToFile(mp3, (stdout, stderr)->
                return console.log stderr if err?
                return console.log 'done'
            )
    enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the spawn system call ends with error ENOENT if the program cannot be found.  In this case, `ffmpeg` is not found, so you have to tell it where it is:

```
proc = new ffmpeg({source:mp4})
    .setFfmpegPath("wherever ffmpeg is installed ") <-- this is the new line
    .toFormat('mp3')
    .saveToFile(mp3, (stdout, stderr)->
            return console.log stderr if err?
            return console.log 'done'
        )
```

More info is available [in a related issue](https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg/issues/129)

Comment: @tldr can you put the `.setFfmpegPath` line before the `.toFormat` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have updated my question to show what worked for me.

Comment: please note, `.setFfmpegPath` is not chainable as it doesn't return `this`.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else coming across this and experiencing the same issue I was `.setFfmpegPath()` requires the full path including the binary not just the directory the binary is in.